# Javascript absolute path to resource file and java class

Tags: java, javascript, html, file, netbeans

I am following and old tutorial (from book) for JavaScript and I have some troubles with making it work. OS is Windows 7/84 and IDE is Netbeans 8.02. Browsers are IE 11, and latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Here is the code:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD><TITLE>Detecting embedded objects (applets, plug-ins, etc.)</TITLE>

        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
<!-- Hide from browsers that do not support JavaScript
            function detectPlugins() {
                if (navigator.plugins.length > 0) {
                    var pluginDescription = "";

                    for (var numPlugins = 0; numPlugins < navigator.plugins.length; numPlugins++) {
                        pluginDescription = pluginDescription + " " + navigator.plugins[numPlugins].name
                    }

                    alert(navigator.plugins.length + " browser plug-ins detected: "
                            + pluginDescription);

                }
                else {
                    alert("No browser plug-ins detected. (Remember, IE doesn't support plug-ins.)")
                }

            }


            function detectApplets() {
                if (document.applets.length > 0) {
                    alert(document.applets.length + " Java applets detected. (Rememember, IE counts applets as embedded objects.)")

                }
                else {
                    alert("No Java applets detected.")
                }
            }

            function detectEmbeds() {

                if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
                    // The user is running IE, so check for objects
                    // embedded using the OBJECT tag.
                    //
                    // The readyState property of an object embedded
                    // using the OBJECT property can contain one of 3
                    // values:
                    // 0 = uninitialized
                    // 1 = loading
                    // 4 = finished loading and ready to go

                    if (document.QTsample.readyState == 4) {
                        alert("Detected the QTsample embedded object");
                    }

                    if (document.clock.readyState == 4) {
                        alert("Detected the clock embedded object");
                    }

                }
                else {
                    if (navigator.appName == "Netscape") {


                        if (document.embeds.length > 0) {
                            alert(document.embeds.length + " embedded object(s) detected.")


                        }
                        else {
                            alert("No embedded objects detected.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // --> Finish hiding
        </SCRIPT>

    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        Two embedded objects appear below:
        <OL>
            <LI><b>A sample movie provided free by QuickTime (Sample.mov).</b>
                Note: IE identifies applets as objects. IE does not recognize browser plug-ins. (IE supports
                ActiveX objects instead of plug-ins.)
            <LI><b>A sample Java applet provided free by Sun Microsystems (JavaClock.class)</b>
                Note: Navigator identifies applets as applets.
        </OL>

        <!--
        You use the OBJECT tag to embed an ActiveX component into a page meant for MSIE;
        you use the EMBED tag to embed a plug-in into a page meant for Navigator.
        Notice the difference between the way the value of the SRC
        variable must be specified.
        // -->

        <OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="250"
                ID="QTsample" CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
            <PARAM name="SRC" VALUE="C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\Sample.mov">
            <PARAM name="AUTOPLAY" VALUE="true">
            <PARAM name="CONTROLLER" VALUE="true">

            <EMBED SRC="file://C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\Sample.mov" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="250" 
                   AUTOPLAY="true" CONTROLLER="true" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">
        </OBJECT>

        <!--
        This Java applet is freely available from Sun Microsystems.  For more info, visit http://java.sun.com/openstudio/applets/clock.html
        Note: the APPLET tag was deprecated in HTML 4.0, which means that programmers are encouraged to use the OBJECT tag
        (instead of the APPLET tag) to embed Java applets in Web pages. Future browsers may not support the APPLET tag.
        // -->

    <APPLET ID="clock" CODEBASE="classes" CODE="JavaClock.class" WIDTH="150" HEIGHT="150">
        <PARAM  NAME="bgcolor"  VALUE="FFFFFF">
        <PARAM  NAME="border"   VALUE="5">
        <PARAM  NAME="ccolor"   VALUE="dddddd">
        <PARAM  NAME="cfont"    VALUE="TimesRoman|BOLD|18">
        <PARAM  NAME="delay"    VALUE="100">
        <PARAM  NAME="hhcolor"  VALUE="0000FF">
        <PARAM  NAME="link"     VALUE="http://java.sun.com/">
        <PARAM  NAME="mhcolor"  VALUE="00FF00">
        <PARAM  NAME="ncolor"   VALUE="000000">
        <PARAM  NAME="nradius"  VALUE="80">
        <PARAM  NAME="shcolor"  VALUE="FF0000">
    </APPLET>
    <P>
    <FORM>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="detect embedded objects" onClick="detectEmbeds()">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="detect plug-ins" onClick="detectPlugins()">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="detect applets" onClick="detectApplets()">
    </FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Originally in book paths were like:

```
<PARAM name="SRC" VALUE="c:\Program Files\QuickTime\Sample.mov">
```

and

```
<EMBED SRC="file://c:\Program Files\QuickTime\Sample.mov" WIDTH="320"
HEIGHT="250" AUTOPLAY="true" CONTROLLER="true"
PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">
```

So I changed that to reflect Windows 7 64 bit program path.
It didn't work. Then I moved Sample.mov to C:\Sample.mov and updated paths in code as well, but that didn't work either? Then I moved Sample.mov to same folder where is html, updated paths just to "Sample.mov" without "C:\". And it worked. I tried all possible combinations prior to that ( / or // or \ or file:///C:/... etc). But it works only without any path.

So in order to make QuickTime video opening in both IE and Firefox I ended up with this:

```
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="250"
        ID="QTsample" CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
    <PARAM name="SRC" VALUE="Sample.mov">
    <PARAM name="AUTOPLAY" VALUE="true">
    <PARAM name="CONTROLLER" VALUE="true">

    <EMBED SRC="Sample.mov" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="250" 
           AUTOPLAY="true" CONTROLLER="true" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">
</OBJECT>
```

**QUESTION 1 IS: how should I make it work with file located outside of document root, like it was supposed in genuine example.**

Unfortunately, I can't make java clock work. I also tried every combination but browser just don't "see" JavaClock class? No matter if I tun it from IDE (Netbeans of directly by opening HTMK page from browser (IE, Firefox or Chrome). Browsers are complaining that JavaClock.class doesn't exist?

**QUESTION 2 IS: how should I make that JavaClock class work as well?.**

Files are located as on this screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found where the error is (blame to the author of the book):
It should be (for CODEBASE) **class** not **classes**

It should be:

```
<APPLET ID="clock" CODEBASE="class" CODE="JavaClock.class" WIDTH="150" HEIGHT="150">
```

instead of

```
<APPLET ID="clock" CODEBASE="classes" CODE="JavaClock.class" WIDTH="150" HEIGHT="150">
```

Now it is ok (even on local machine):

[image]